# Recent spam messages with gibberish text

Tags: discussion, flagging

We seem to be getting a lot of spam messages recently from various sources.

I noticed in one of three posts that a user (sorry - can't specify who, now) had run out of spam flags. Would it be possible to assign additional spam flags (only) to users to avoid this (running to infinite flags for 10K+)?

Comment: Just a (colorful) note: SE has given their blessing to destroy spam accounts as soon as they post a single gibberish question. So, mods, be ruthless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's necessary. Users get more spam flags every day and we have a good many users who actively flag, not to mention mods who don't have a limit. Besides, if a user continues to have their flags be validated they will get more over time.